# How to change default video card in a laptop?

Tags: laptop, video, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I have an Asus [VivoBook S15 X510UF](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-VivoBook-15-X510UF/specifications/), with an Intel integrated video card and a Nvidia GeForce MX130.

In the Nvidia settings, I see [only 3D options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahSww.png), but I want to set the settings from the Nvidia panel rather than the Intel one, so I want to change my default graphics card.

I know it's done from the BIOS, but I have UEFI and on **Graphics configuration under the advanced section of the advanced mode** I see only [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkXPr.jpg).

How can I change graphics card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely can't. In most laptops integrated Intel card (iGPU) is the only full-fledged GPU and is responsible for driving outputs. NVIDIA GPU can render images to a memory buffer, but iGPU is used to display them. Only a few business-oriented laptops can use solely NVIDIA GPU.